# C++ при загрузке ответа, сделанного при помощи get запроса русский текст преобразуется в кракозябру

Tags: c++

Делаю бота для VK на плюсах, использую эту функцию для загрузки ответа в json формате. Всё отлично скачивается, но русский текст преобразуется в непонятные символы. system("chcp 1251 > nul");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); - перепробовал всё это, но результата не дало. Текст передаётся в этой части кода  `if (!WinHttpReadData(Request, (LPVOID)Outbuffer, Size, &downloaded)) { cout << GetLastError() << endl; } buffer += Outbuffer;`

```
string down(HINTERNET Request) {
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    DWORD Size{}, downloaded{};
    char* Outbuffer;
    string buffer{};
    do {
        Size = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(Request, &Size)) {
            cout << "Download error" << endl;
            nlohmann::json err;
            err["failed"] = 2;
            string f = err.dump();
            return f;
        }
        Outbuffer = new char[Size + 1];
        if (!Outbuffer) {
            cout << "lack of memory" << endl;
            Size = 0;
        }
        else {
            ZeroMemory(Outbuffer, Size + 1);
            if (!WinHttpReadData(Request, (LPVOID)Outbuffer, Size, &downloaded)) {
                cout << GetLastError() << endl;
            }
            buffer += Outbuffer;
            delete[] Outbuffer;
        }
    } while (Size > 0);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: с вероятностью 99% там utf-8, а Вы пытаетесь как cp1251...

Comment: @KoVadim, можно поподробнее?

Comment: есть разные кодировки. И если кодировка терминала не совпадает с кодировкой текста, то может быть все что угодно. Например, некрасивый текст или "иероглифы". Что делать? разобраться, какая там кодировка и перекодировать.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну в стринге же и лежит UTF8, или я не прав?

Comment: вполне возможно. Но когда Вы выводите его на терминал, то Вы "копируете байты" а терминал уже интерпретирует эти байты по своей кодировке (по умолчанию это 866), или выставленная и показывает в ней.

Comment: @KoVadim, мне не нужно выводить его никуда. Мне лишь нужно, чтобы при отладке программы в стринге лежали не иероглифы, а русские и латинские буквы. Я сталкивался с тем, что при начальной инициализации стринга русским текстом всё нормально, а при вводе с клавиатуры - плохо, но это решается через SetConsoleCp, здесь же эта "волшебная" команда не помогает, можете что-то посоветовать?

Comment: ох. что лежит в массиве байт зависит только от Вашей интерпретации. На самом деле нет ни русских букв (кириллицы, если точнее), не латинских. там просто байтики. У Вас работала "начальная инициализация", потому что в этом случае компилятор использовал кодировку  текста программы. SetConsoleCP просто указывает, как именно байтики преобразовывать в символы и обратно. Если в отладчике видны символы не так, как Вы ожидаете, это значит, что отладчик использует другую кодировку. А магических команд не будет - их нет. Увидел в коде `if (!Outbuffer) {` - с вероятностью 99.9% оно у Вас никогда не будет

Comment: @KoVadim, "как именно байтики преобразовывать в символы и обратно" то есть если я просто сделаю сравнение полученной строки со строкой, введённой на кириллице, то получу TRUE? Так я уже пробовал - не проходит

Comment: Если Вы ожидали TRUE, то значит Вы ничего не поняли. Потому что, если с латиницей и цифрами все очевидно (ну кроме uft-16), то для кириллицы все сложно. Для корректного сравнения строк, они должны быть как минимум **в одной кодировке**. Если кодировки разные, то с большой вероятностью строки будут представлены по разному. Скорее всего внеконтакт возвращает utf-8 (это сейчас стандарт де факто), где для кириллицы используется 2 байта на символ, а с консоли вводите либо 866 кодировку, либо cp1251 - и там и там для кириллицы используется 1 байт и такие строки в байтах даже будет иметь разную длину

Comment: @KoVadim, я пробовал то же самое перекачать в wstring сначала, но там была ещё более полная ахинея, именно иероглифы, при преобразовании обратно в стринг часть букв переехала нормально, а другая - нет. Так как пихать в стринг utf8 нормально?

Comment: я не знаю, как именно происходит это "перекачивание". Если Вам приходит utf-8, то не нужно его "пихать" - оно уже там будет. Если нужно преобразовывать, то можно конечно написать свои функции (но только в образовательных целях!) или пользоваться iconv или MultiByteToWideChar

Comment: @KoVadim, дело в том, что я не до конца понимаю, что делают те или иные команды в функции. Насколько я понял, этот оператор  ```if (!WinHttpReadData(Request, (LPVOID)Outbuffer, Size, &downloaded)) {``` каким-то образом помещает значение в Outbuffer, хоть на него и не стоит указателя. Вероятно нужно изменить что-то в этой части ```buffer += Outbuffer;```, чтобы указать кодировку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Outbuffer - уже указатель. Так что проблем для функции WinHttpReadData что то туда записать нет. После того, как все данные были получены (в самом конце функции перед return) можно конвертнуть данные в другую кодировку, если в этом есть необходимость

Comment: @KoVadim, в Outbuffer после ```if (!WinHttpReadData(Request, (LPVOID)Outbuffer, Size, &downloaded))``` приходит текст с крокозябрами. Возможно Outbuffer стоит объявлять не как char*, а как-то по-другому?

Comment: Он там скорее всего нормальный, просто Вы его неверно интерпретирует

Comment: @KoVadim, а как правильно? И что Вы подразумеваете под понятием интерпретации?

Comment: Показывайте скриншот Ваших страданий, возможно там действительно не все так сложно. Интерпретация кодировок - это как квадрат Малевича - кому произведение искусства, кому то просто черный квадрат

Comment: @Petuha, а Вы знаете какой именно в данном примере к Вам должен прийти русский текст ? К примеру первое слово знаете ?

Comment: @KoVadim, весь json приходит правильно, есть лишь одна проблема: вместо "text":"С‚РµСЃС должно быть "text":"тест.

Comment: @Optimus1, всё приходит правильно, кроме кириллицы

Comment: у Вас приходит нормальный utf-8, который Вы пытаетесь смотреть как cp1251. То есть, ещё раз. Вам приходит нормальный корректный текст в UTF-8. Сохраните в текстовый файл, откройте любым редактором с поддержкой uft-8 и все будет корректно

Comment: @KoVadim, если использовать костыль с файлом, то в файле всё отображается нормально, однако никакие операции сравнения с этой строкой я провести не могу, так как проблема с иероглифами остаётся. Может быть, это как-то в VS настроить нужно?

Comment: @Petuha, хотите проводить операцию сравнения, то проводите ее корректно в одинаковой кодировке. std::string my_string = u8"Ваш сравниваемый текст" и сравнивайте my_string с присланным текстом.

Comment: @Optimus1,  при вставке полученного текста в текстовый файл, я вижу в нём нормальные русские буквы, всё просто отлично. Однако при повторном чтение всё идёт прямо и налево. Буквы будто заколдованные. Однако при попытке считать эти же буквы, но уже из другой программы, всё происходит просто и великолепно. Не понимаю, почему оно не может их считать именно в этом случае.

Comment: @Petuha, при повторном чтение откуда и куда, дайте больше конкретики :) Что значит прямо и налево ? Почему не назад и в право ? Что за эти же буквы, что за другая программа ? Что вы там колдуете ? Что вам нужно сделать с полученными байтами, которые вы приняли от сервера ?

Comment: @Optimus1, спасибо за подсказку с u8, можно просто добавлять эти два долбанных символа и всё будет просто супер. Смотрите, я беру и качаю json. Затем пихаю его в файл. В файле все буквы на кириллице отображаются нормально, без кракозябр. Однако при повторном чтении из ранее созданного файла русские буквы снова перевоплощаются. А про другую программу - я сделал тест, в котором считывал текст из файла с буквами на кириллице, и там всё проходило успешно, и даже в отладчике я видел русские буквы. Я решил, что просто смогу закинуть этот буфер в файл, а потом снова считать его.

Comment: @Petuha, вопрос в том, как вы проверяете "перевоплащение" считанного из файла текста. Опять через консоль ? Если да, то без разницы, выводите ли вы на консоль сразу полученный json или считанный из текстового файла, кодировка то одна и таже.

Comment: @Optimus1, через отладку проверяю. А как стринг перекодировать нормально? Просто я накидал прогу, которая считывает из файла русский, и нормально там всё отображается, хоть я и не перекодировал строку.

Comment: @Petuha, текстовый файл в кодировке utf8 ? Если да,  и если не секрет, что за прога, которая считывает и самое главное, как и в чем она отображает текст ? Перекодировать string знаю только, что можно с помошью winapi-шной функции, KoVadim выше ее указывал - MultiByteToWideChar. Но мне кажется, ван нужно определится, ЧТО ВАМ ВООБЩЕ НУЖНО СДЕЛАТЬ С ПРИНЯТЫМ json текстом.

Comment: @Optimus1, похоже, я делаю лютую херню, и добавления u8 перед строкой, с которой я собираюсь сравнивать, мне будет достаточно. Спасибо всем, кто помогал!

Answer (score -1):

Просто забить на эти иероглифы и добавлять u8 перед каждой строкой, с которой буду сравнивать скачанный текст. Например, `if(buffer == u8"Привет"){...}`